# jquery how to take out a jquery function outside the onready function?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the next function inside my onready function to detect a button submit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    some code....
    /////Busqueda
    $('#search-form input[id=search]').val("Example Value!");   
    // When you click on #search
    $("#search-form input[id=search-submit]").click(function(){
        var valor = $('#search-form input[id=search]').val();
        console.log(valor);
        // If the value is equal to "Search..."
        if(valor == "Example Value!") {
            cargarApps(numCol, 1);
        }

    }); 

 });
<div id="busqueda">
    <form id="search-form">
        <fieldset>
            <input id="search" type="text">
            <input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I´m doing a search element so in the "some code..." i load all my elements for the search and when the user clicks submit it does the code from the search but the "some code..." executes again erasing the results of my search.
Does anyone knows a way to avoid that???
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used an input type submit. After clicking the button it first executes the javascript event attached to it and then makes a postback.

I would change the input type submit to a button element. But if you want to keep your element you can return at the end of your click event false to interrupt the postback.

Comment: Thanks i used your 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

$('#selector').click(function(){//some code});

$(document).ready(function(){//some code});

</script>
```

This will now work all the time for id selector.